# Clarity around Advanced Segment defintion

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am hoping to get some clarity around an advanced segment I created.  For context, our website spans multiple domains.

For reasons I wont get into, I created an advanced segment that looks for pages containing my subdomain of interest (subdomain.site.com).

I want to ensure that my interpretation of this advanced segment is accurate.  Simply, it flags all visits to our entire domain that viewed at least one page on my subdomain of interest?

If I am off, what does this advanced segment represent?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably a better way to do this is to created the advanced segment by filtering on the hostname attribute. If you set the hostname to Matches Exactly subdomain.site.com, then when you filter you will only see pages, visits, etc for traffic that matches that subdomain.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  Basically I don't want to restrict my data to the subdomain, but I do want to filter visits that had a least 1 pageview on the subdomain of interest.  I am interested to see what other pages they might view.  Does my advanced segment above accurately accomplish this?